# rsync completed in both directions, but size of directories is different. How it's possible?

Tags: command-line, rsync, disk-usage, diff, macos

I want to sync 2 directories (`/src` & `/dst`) to mirror all the files in both of them.

Here is a steps:

1. `sudo rsync -vaP --stats /src  /dst` -> completed without errors
2. `sudo rsync -vaP --stats /dst /src` -> completed without errors
3. `diff -rq /src /dst`-> doesn't show any diffs.
4. `du -s /src && du -s /dst` shows different sizes (10% diff).

How it's possible? I'm completely stuck with this dilemma.

Comment: Search about `sparse files`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Sparse files may be expanded on copy when the `-S` flag is not used.  (Will make the destination take more space)
- Hard links within the tree may be expanded to separate files on copy when the `-H` flag is not used.  (Will make the destination take more space)
- Filesystems may have different allocation sizes.  A one-byte file may take up 512 bytes of disk allocation on one filesystem and may take up 4096 bytes (or even more) on another.  If your tree has a lot of small files, this will make a large difference.  (Destination may take more or less space depending on the particulars)
- Directories may be much larger than necessary to hold the current contents on some filesystems.  When the contents are copied, the directory will be smaller on the destination.  Not normally a big deal, but some pathological directories can be enormous.  (Will make the destination take less space)

It's also possible for filesystems to have different compression/deduplication/redundancy settings leading to different storage requirements for the data.  But that's less common, and even when present the differences aren't always visible via `du`.

Comment: There might also be hard-linked files, which (without the `-H` option) will be copied as separate files.

Comment: Quite true.  I'll add that in as well.