# rsync folder size discrepancy

Tags: rsync, file-copy, synology

I'm running rsync between two Synology NAS machines. However, after running, there is a huge size discrepancy between the source and destination folders - as in, the source folder reads as 6.64 TB/325664 files, and the destination folder reads as 9.53 TB/548169 files.

The rsync command I'm running (as a task in the Synology GUI - the DSM) is:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -ac --log-file="/volume1/NAS/backup_logs/logs/log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%m%S).txt"\
-e "ssh -p 53040" /volume1/{source folder} \
{user}@my.server.address:/volume1/{destination folder}
```

When I compare the actual contents of the source and destination files and sub-folders, all the names and sizes appear to be the same. There are too many folders to do more than spot-check, but every one I look at is the same. The files themselves are a hodgepodge - gifs, tiffs, JPGs, PDFs, XML, text, MP3s, video files, etc. Some of them likely contain hyperlinks, but none should have executable code.

I've found some explanations that mention 'hard links' and 'sparse files', but nothing that says exactly how to find them or what to do about them in order to produce a destination folder the same size as the source.

Comment: Do you have _sparse_ files? If so, remember to use `rsync` with its `--sparse` option, or the holes in those files would be filled in by zeros.  Sparse files are commonly used for swap files and VM disk images.  Hard links require the `--hard-links` option, or they would end up as multiple duplicate files.  Running the sync again with those option would likely be quick (if you drop the `-c` option; with it, it would require reading the contents of the files) and would sort the issues out.  This is not an answer as I don't know for sure that this is your issue.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda.  I don't know if I have sparse files or hard links.  But is there any danger in putting those options in, just in case?  If not, where should they go in the command line?

Comment: There's no problem with adding the `--sparse` option. The only issue with the `--hard-links` option is that `rsync` then needs to maintain a table of all files so that it can detect hard links. Very occasionally this can run a small system out of memory but you'll realise if that's an issue when `rsync` dies with an `out of memory` error.

Comment: There should be no harm in adding the `-S` option "just in case", on many filesystems it is cheap to get the number of blocks allocated (using the stat or fstat or fstatat system calls) so you can tell if a file is sparse or not. Whilst there are lots of reasons for sparse files one common one is file system images for virtual machines,

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561326

Comment: Your destination claims to have many more files than your source, you can use rsync again (see https://superuser.com/a/734562/439215) to determine what they are.  By default rsync won't be deleting files from the destination to make it match, so anything that was there before the rsync will still be there as well.