# Why does `du` report that my `rsync` backup is not the same size as the original?

Tags: files, rsync, backup, disk-usage, ext4

I'm creating a backup of my `$HOME` directory on an external storage drive using `rsync`, using the following options:

```
--archive --xattrs --hard-links
```

After a fresh backup, `du` reports that the sizes of some of the backed-up directories differ from the sizes of the originals. For example, `du -bs ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/datareporting/archived/2024-01/` outputs `3198125`, whereas the equivalent command for the backup copy outputs `3194029`.

However, adding a `*` and running `du -bs ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/datareporting/archived/2024-01/*` and summing the output file sizes gives `3165357`, and the equivalent command for the backup copy gives the same result.

So, my questions are:

- Is `rsync` failing to backup all of the data under `~/.mozilla`? Or am I just using `du` incorrectly?
- Why does `du` report different file sizes for the backup copy of `.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/datareporting/archived/2024-01/` vs. the original, but reports the same sizes for the files contained in the directories?
- If I'm using `du` incorrectly, how can I accurately confirm that my backup is exactly the same size as my original `$HOME` directory?

Notes:

- I have `shopt -s dotglob` set, so dotfiles aren't responsible for the size differences reported by `du`.
- My `$HOME` filesystem exists on an SSD while my backup drive is an HDD.
- Both filesystems are `ext4`.
- I'm on Debian 12.

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561302/77996

Answer (score 1):

Let's address each of your questions one by one for clarity:

#### 1. Is rsync failing to backup all of the data under ~/.mozilla? Or am I just using du incorrectly?

Based on the information you've provided, it doesn't sound like `rsync` is failing to backup your data. The fact that when you sum up the sizes of the individual files within the directories, the totals match between the original and the backup indicates that `rsync` is successfully copying all the data. The discrepancy you're seeing in the total size reported by `du` for the directory as a whole vs. the sum of its contents is likely due to differences in how the filesystems allocate space for the directory's metadata and the files themselves, rather than an issue with `du` or `rsync`. `du` calculates the space used by directories and files based on the filesystem's block size and allocation, which can vary, especially between different drives (SSD vs. HDD), even if they use the same filesystem type (ext4).

#### 2. Why does du report different file sizes for the backup copy of .mozilla/firefox//datareporting/archived/2024-01/ vs. the original, but reports the same sizes for the files contained in the directories?

`du` reports different sizes for the directories themselves because of how the filesystem on each drive allocates space for directories and stores metadata. Each filesystem can handle directory metadata and block allocation differently, which can result in slight discrepancies in reported sizes for directories, even when the files within those directories have identical sizes. This can be influenced by factors like the filesystem's block size, the number of files in the directory (affecting the directory's size due to metadata storage), and any filesystem-specific optimizations or differences in handling metadata. Since you mentioned that the file sizes match perfectly when summed up, this reinforces the idea that the files themselves are correctly backed up, and the size variance stems from directory metadata or filesystem allocation differences.

#### 3. If I'm using du incorrectly, how can I accurately confirm that my backup is exactly the same size as my original $HOME directory?

To accurately confirm the integrity and completeness of your backup, especially when dealing with critical data like your `$HOME` directory, size comparison using `du` may not be the most reliable method due to the reasons mentioned above. Instead, consider using the following methods:

- **Checksum Verification**: You can use tools like `md5sum` or `sha256sum` to generate checksums of files in both the original and backup directories and then compare these checksums to ensure they match. This can be done with a combination of find, xargs, and the checksum tool of your choice to recursively process all files.

  ```bash
  # Generate checksums for the original directory
  find /path/to/original -type f -exec sha256sum {} + > original_checksums.txt

  # Generate checksums for the backup directory
  find /path/to/backup -type f -exec sha256sum {} + > backup_checksums.txt

  # Compare the checksum files
  diff original_checksums.txt backup_checksums.txt
  ```

  If the `diff` command shows no output, it means all files match perfectly.
- **Rsync in Checksum Mode**: Running `rsync` with the `-c` option forces it to compare file contents (checksums) rather than sizes and modification times, which can be a more reliable way to ensure that all files have been copied correctly and are identical.

These methods focus on the content of the files rather than their allocated space on disk, providing a more accurate verification of backup integrity.

Comment: Note that the order that find traverses the directories will affect the checksum that you calculate. To compare the checksums of two directory trees, you will need to ensure that the files in both trees are read in the exact same order.

Comment: It is also worthwhile to note that that the directories in a new backup have the minimum number of blocks to hold the current files, while the original filesystem will have undergone create/delete cycles that increased the size of a directory, but never shrink it.