Rsync backup is almost twice as big as source
I'm using rsync to back up my home directory:
time rsync -iia --append-verify --progress --exclude cloudDrive/ /home /usr/local/share/applications /etc/yum.repos.d /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/"2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00" 1> /tmp/out.log 2>/tmp/err.log

I had to suspend it because it was taken too long:
real    1305m43.016s
user    0m1.691s
sys     0m5.394s

du shows that home in the source is 64 G while home in the backup is 23 G. However this is expected because I cancelled the backup so it didn't finish.
Closer inspection shows that for the same directory there's a big discrepancy in the backup and the source:
du -h --max-depth=1 $HOME/.android/avd
5.1G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
5.7G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
3.6G    .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
15G     .android/avd

$ du -h --max-depth=1 $HOME/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00\:06\:05+02\:00/home/user/.android/avd/ 2> /tmp/throwaway2.txt
5.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
5.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
9.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/

Why is the rsync backup 6 GB more than the original directory?

I haven't decoded your rsync command, but your observed behavior matches "storing the backup in the backup" mistake I made decades ago. Check your rsync command, look at its outputs, look at sudo lsof -c rsync when it's running.

@waltinator Read their command again. They are excluding the directory holding the backup.

@waltinator "storing the backup in the backup" I don't think I'm doing this. What do you mean? I'm backing up my home directory.

Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561302/rsync-completed-in-both-directions-but-size-of-directories-is-different-how-it/561326#561326

The discrepency is caused by the differences in the way that ls and ranger via du determine the size of files and directories, compared to the default way that du does it. The du keybinding of ranger uses du shell -p du --max-depth=1 -h --apparent-size where as du -sh does not use --apparent-size.
From man du:

--apparent-size
print  apparent  sizes  rather than device usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation,
indirect blocks, and the like

For /home/user/.android/avd and /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/:

ranger (du shell -p du --max-depth=1 -h --apparent-size)
  - source 21 G
  - destination 21 G


ls -al
  - source 12 bytes
  - destination 22 bytes


du -sh
  - source 15G
  - destination 21G



The discrepency is due to the different disk usage on the source (HDD) and cloud storage drive. apparent--size is the actual size of the file or directory so it will always be the same on any file system. However the disk usage of a file or directory depends on the file system.
A file's apparent size can be smaller or larger than the disk usage size. For example, an uncompressed file or directory's apparent-size would be larger than the disk usage space of a compressed file or directory. For sparse files, apparent-size would be smaller than the disk usage space. By default, du gives the size of the file in number of disk blocks therefore due to block allocation smaller files may take up more disk space 2.
Although the contents (size) in bytes of both source and destination are the same, the amount of space it takes up is less on the local HDD compared to the amount it takes up on the cloud storage server disk.
To avoid this discrepency, apparent--size should be used to show file space usage when comparing source and destination files from rsync.
The -s option of ls inserts an extra column to the left showing the actual on-disk size for files1. The on-disk file or directory size of ls -s is not only different from du --sh and ranger (du --apparent size), the source and destination ls -s on-disk file or directory size are different from one another which is expected due to reasons given above.
NOTE: The on-disk file and directory size shown by ls -s is different from du --apparent-size because ls -s only shows the size of the top level contents of a directory while du is recursive and shows the size of all directories and their subdirectories. The on-disk file and directory size of the source and destination ls -s are different likely because the source and destination are different file systems and so have their own way of storing files on disk.
source
$ du -h --max-depth=2 .android/avd
44K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
12K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
1.9G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
64K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
5.1G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
44K     .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
3.0G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
5.7G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
44K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
64K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
3.6G    .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
15G     .android/avd

user@fedora:~$ du -h --apparent-size --max-depth=2 .android/avd
31K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
42      .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
1.9G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
64K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
5.6G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
31K     .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
3.0G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
5.9G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
32K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
64K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
9.6G    .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     .android/avd

destination
user@fedora:~$ du -h --max-depth=2 /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00\:06\:05+02\:00/home/user/.android/avd/ 2> /tmp/throwaway2.txt
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
1.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
76K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
5.5K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
12K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
3.0G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
4.0K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
4.0K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
76K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
9.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/

$ du -h --apparent-size --max-depth=2 /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00\:06\:05+02\:00/home/user/.android/avd/ 2> /tmp/throwaway2.txt
31K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
1.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
64K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
42      /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
0       /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
3.0G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
31K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
0       /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
32K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
0       /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
64K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
9.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/

Discrepencies
source
user@fedora:~$ du -h --max-depth=2 .android/avd
44K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
12K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
1.9G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
64K     .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
5.1G    .android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
44K     .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
3.0G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
0       .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
5.7G    .android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
44K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
0       .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
64K     .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
3.6G    .android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
15G     .android/avd

$ ls -asl .android/avd/
total 12
0 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 316 Sep  1 18:54 .
0 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 380 Sep  4 01:07 ..
0 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 710 Sep  2 17:33 Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 134 Sep  1 00:41 Medium_Phone_API_35.ini
0 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 672 Sep  4 01:11 Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 132 Sep  1 18:54 Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.ini
0 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 738 Sep  2 03:28 Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 169 Sep  1 01:03 Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.ini

destination
user@fedora:~$ du -h --max-depth=2 /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00\:06\:05+02\:00/home/user/.android/avd/ 2> /tmp/throwaway2.txt
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/modem_simulator
1.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/snapshots
76K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/data
5.5K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
12K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/data
3.0G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/snapshots
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/modem_simulator
4.0K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd/tmpAdbCmds
5.9G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
48K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/modem_simulator
4.0K    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/tmpAdbCmds
76K     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd/data
9.6G    /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/

$ ls -asl /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/
total 22
4 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 4096 Sep  1 18:54 .
4 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 4096 Sep  4 01:07 ..
4 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 4096 Sep  2 17:33 Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
1 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  134 Sep 27 00:22 Medium_Phone_API_35.ini
4 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 4096 Sep  4 01:11 Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
1 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  132 Sep 27 00:22 Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.ini
4 drwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 4096 Sep  2 03:28 Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
1 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  169 Sep 27 00:22 Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.ini

source
ranger /home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd (du shell -p du --max-depth=1 -h --apparent-size)
5.6G    ./Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
5.9G    ./Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
9.6G    ./Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     .

destination
ranger /home/user/cloudDrive/Backups/2024-09-27T00:06:05+02:00/home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd (du shell -p du --max-depth=1 -h --apparent-size)
5.6G    ./Medium_Phone_API_35.avd
5.9G    ./Pixel_Fold_API_VanillaIceCream.avd
9.6G    ./Pixel_8_Pro_API_32.avd
21G     .


Your answer is overall correct and does address the question but it can be more concise and doesn't need to be anywhere near as long and can be covered in a single paragraph. The person who asked the question and others are more likely to read that that they are to read the entirety of your answer because it is more than what is needed to convey the point. I'm not saying that it is a bad answer because it isn't but there are some things that can be done to clean it up and make it more direct while also providing an adequate answer. For those reasons, I have upvoted your answer.

The commands given in the question show that du is run with the same set of options on two sets of files and that there is a discrepancy between the result.  In your answer, you say the discrepancy is due to file sparseness and running du with different options.  Also, the question does not mention ranger at all.  If anything, it's rsync that is not run with --sparse that fills out the holes in the files. But your answer does not even mention this.

Thanks for all the feedback. I wanted this answer to serve as a reference. @Kusalananda I wasn't aware of the --sparse option in rsync. I've updated my answer. Is there anyway to test whether a file is sparse or not?

@bit Having du and ls report different sizes for the same file is usually a good indicator that the file is sparse. One will by default report the size of the file minus the holes, and the other will report the apparent size, including the holes.
